# What does the following limits question mean?

Tags: limits, continuity

Using the properties of limits, The question asks find the following limit using the **observation** $\lim_{x\to c}x=c$

Question:  $$ \lim_{x\to c} (x^3-4x^2-3)$$

Answer: $$ \lim_{x\to c} (x^3-4x^2-3)$$ $$= \lim_{x\to c} (x^3) - \lim_{x\to c} (4x^2)-\lim_{x\to c} (3)$$ $$=c^3-4c^2-3$$

**My question is, does the answer to the question above mean this?**:

$$ \lim_{x\to c} (x^3-4x^2-3)=c^3-4c^2-3$$
Or in another words: "as $x$ approaches $c$, $ (x^3-4x^2-3)$ approaches the limit $c^3-4c^2-3$"?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in general if all limits exist and polynomial $f,g$ then $$\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = f(a) + g(a)$$ means that $\lim_{x \to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = f(a) + g(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should note that $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = f(c)$ is only true if $f$ is continuous at $c$ and should be noted in your answer - but it's trivial to see all terms are continuous since they are polynomials.